# Fundamental group of a wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, fundamental-groups

The Van Kampen theorem implies that, given two path-connected (pointed) topological spaces $(X,p)$ and $(Y,q)$, we can relate the fundamental group of their wegde sum with both their fundamental groups: $$\pi_1(X\vee Y,p\vee q)\cong\pi_1(X,p)\ast\pi_1(Y,q).\qquad(\star)$$
Here, $\ast$ means the free product of groups. Note that the previous holds *if* we require the wedge point $p\vee q$ to have a simply-connected neighborhood in $X\vee Y$. This always happens if both $X$ and $Y$ are locally simply-connected.

Now, I am trying to construct a counter-example of the fact $(\star)$. For this, I am looking at a space that is *not* locally simply-connected: the [Hawaiian earrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring). I denote it as $H\subset{\bf R}^2$, and I take the basepoint $p\in H$ to be the “wild” point $(0,0)$. Now, I take $Y$ to be a circle of radius $2$ and centered at $(2,0)$ in ${\bf R}^2$, and I also take its basepoint $q=(0,0)$. Surely, the wedge sum $(H\vee Y,p\vee q)$ is not locally simply-connected, for the wedge point does not have a simply-connected neighborhood.

My question is: **Does that provide a counter-example?** My reasoning is as follows:

$\;(1)\;$ The wedge sum is homeomorphic to $H$.

$\;(2)\;$ In that case we have that $\pi_1(H\vee Y,p\vee q)\cong\pi_1(H,p)$.

$\;(3)\;$ We see that $\pi_1(H,p)\ast{\bf Z}\not\cong\pi_1(H,p)$.

I am unsure about steps $(1)$ and $(3)$ above. For $(1)$, a homeomorphism would be given by shifting every circle once to the left. For $(3)$, this is because we're adding a free generator to the (infinite) presentation of $\pi_1(H,p)$? But That does not convince me, since the free group on countably generators has the property that is is invariant under adding countably many free generators.

Please correct me wherever I am wrong!

Comment: Your steps (1) and (2) are correct. But (3) is wrong, or at least it is not clear why would such thing hold. For example consider the free group $F(A)$ over an infinite alphabet $A$. Then $F(A)*\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $F(A)$. But of course this doesn't answer (3) because the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring is not free. But it is so complicated, that I doubt you'll be able to show (3), even if it is true (which I doubt).

Comment: Yes, the example you gave for $(3)$ is what I wrote about in the question, thus me suspecting it is more difficult than that. Thanks for your insight on the first two steps though!

Comment: Do you know an explicit description of $\pi_1(H)$? Specifically, as locally eventually constant transfinite words on a countable alphabet.

Comment: I think asking if $\pi_1(H,h)\ast \mathbb{Z}\cong \pi_1(H,h)$ is the wrong question because you are not interested in whether there *is* such an isomorphism.  Instead, you're asking if the *specific* map $\pi_1(H,h)\ast \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \pi_1(H,h)$ given by van Kampen is an isomorphism.  This is a more specific question, so may be easier to answer.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to answer either question!

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't know of an explicit presentation of $\pi_1(H)$. The only thing I know is it surjects onto the Specker group.
Regarding your comments: maybe there's a (way) simpler counter-example that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot answer the question whether $\pi_1(H,p)\ast{\bf Z}\not\cong\pi_1(H,p)$. The fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring is a fairly complicated object as you can see in

> Morgan, John W., and Ian Morrison. "A van Kampen theorem for weak joins." Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 3.3 (1986): 562-576.

I guess that $\pi_1(H,p)\ast{\bf Z}\cong\pi_1(H,p)$, but I do not know how to prove it.

Anyway, a counterexample to $(*)$ can be found in [Fundamental group of wedge sum of two coni over Hawaiian earrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2788471). This example is closely related to the Hawaiian earring. It shows that the wedge of two contractible spaces can have a highly non-trivial fundamental group.

**Update.**

Although the Hawaiian earring behaves "locally bad" at $p = (0,0)$, it is nevertheless true that
$$\pi_1(H \vee Y, p \vee q) \cong \pi:1(H.p) * \pi_1(Y,q) . \tag{1}$$
The reason is that $Y$ behaves "locally nice " at $q$. If **one** of spaces involved in the wedge is "locally nice" at its basepoint, we can prove $(1)$.

See the answers to [Under what conditions $\pi_1(X \vee Y) \approx \pi_1(X) * \pi_1(Y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625240)