# Is $G*G \cong G$ where $G$ is the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-product

Let $X$ be the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) and let $x_0$ be the point $(0,0)$. Consider the wedge sum $Y:=X\vee X=X\coprod X/x_0\sim x_0$. Then using $\Bbb N=\{1,3,5,\dots\}\cup \{2,4,6,\dots\}$, $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$. My question is: Do we have $G*G\cong G$ (isomorphic as groups), where $G=\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

If this is not true, but this will be a counterexample of the statement that $\pi_1(X_1\vee X_2)\cong \pi_1(X_1)*\pi_1(X_2)$ for path-connected topological spaces $X_1,X_2$.

(This is true if the wedge point has a neighborhood that deformation retracts onto itself, by the van Kampen theorem).

The group $G$ is [quite complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring#Fundamental_group), and I have no idea whether $G*G$ is isomorphic to $G$ or not.

**Edit.** It is known that the $H_1(X)$, which is the abelianization of $G$, is [$(\prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z) \oplus (\prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z/\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring#First_singular_homology), so one way to prove that $G*G\not\cong G$ is showing $$
\left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right) \oplus \left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z/\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right) \not\cong \left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right) \oplus \left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z/\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right) \oplus \left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right) \oplus \left( \prod_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z/\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \Bbb Z \right).$$

Comment: Are you looking for a counterexample to $\pi_1(X_1\vee X_2)\cong \pi_1(X_1)*\pi_1(X_2)$ or are interested especially in $G \cong G*G$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Actually the latter one. I've seen a counterexample of the former one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788471/fundamental-group-of-wedge-sum-of-two-coni-over-hawaiian-earrings

Comment: The abelianizations should indeed not be isomorphic as can be observed by taking their duals.

Comment: Is the natural topology of the fundamental group of the earring visible purely from the group structure, i.e. can we define it just using group theoretic language? If so, I imagine there is a topological proof this isomorphism can't hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a negative answer by applying a result stated [on math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353241/free-product-decompositions-of-the-fundamental-group-of-hawaiian-earrings): For every free product decomposition $G = G_1 * G_2$, one of the two factors is free of finite rank. Since $G$ is not free of finite rank, there cannot be an isomorphism $G = G * G$.